# How can I estimate bandwidth for My .Net application (WPF)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, networking, bandwidth

I have developed a WPF application (C#), which is used to manage a large number of subscribers. The company that owns this application has a lot of branches throughout the country and they want to deploy this application for each branch via LAN. They want to know the required bandwidth for this application.

How can I measure the bandwidth my application uses per user to calculate the required bandwidth for the LAN, where the application will work.

I'm using SQL Server 2012 at the backend. The subscribers' account information is maintained in the db.

Answer (score 1):

Some monitoring application like NetBalancer (https://netbalancer.com/) can provide you the bandwidth being consumed by your application. I would recommend estimate it for all major feature of your application and have projected number of usage frequency of these features. From both this variable you can provide an estimated bandwidth requirement.
Also keep monitoring the app once it is hosted on LAN to get a more realistic number and also keep in mind the usage pattern for each department might be different so each instance of your application might have different set of bandwidth requirement.

Answer (score 0):

[sys.dm_exec_connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-connections-transact-sql) could be used to measure bandwidth per connection.

You can just fire few basic queries which are mostly fired from you WPF client to sql in a single connection and measure a approximate bandwidth required.